# which values are available in event.target and how to access it

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, openlayers, angular-openlayers

i am following an online workshop and examples which you can find it here :

```
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mouse-position.html
```

in the example posted in the above mentioned link, in both of the functions

```
var projectionSelect = document.getElementById('projection');
projectionSelect.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
  mousePositionControl.setProjection(event.target.value);//<------HERE
});
```

And

```
var precisionInput = document.getElementById('precision');
precisionInput.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
  var format = createStringXY(event.target.valueAsNumber);//<------HERE
  mousePositionControl.setCoordinateFormat(format);
});
```

the following attributes were used respectively

```
 event.target.value , event.target.valueAsNumber
```

however, when i tried to run the code in visual studio codes, it underscores both of

```
 .value  and .valueAsNumber
```

with red, which mean such attriburtes do not exist.
please let me know which attributes are valid to be used so i can have access to the values contained in

```
 event.target
```

**code**:

```js
ngOnInit(){
    this.todaydate2 = this.myservice.showTodayDate();
    this.value = this.myservice.observablesTest();

    var mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
      className: 'custom-mouse-position',
      coordinateFormat: createStringXY(7),
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
      // be placed within the map.
      target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
      undefinedHTML: '',//for what to be rendered when the mouse leaves map scope: values https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_MousePosition-MousePosition.html
    });

    this.map = new Map({
      controls: defaultControls().extend([mousePositionControl]),
      target: 'map-container',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZSource({
            url: 'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
          })
        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([13.2232,52.4059]),
        zoom: 6
      })
    });

    var projectionSelect = document.getElementById('projection');
    projectionSelect.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
      mousePositionControl.setProjection(event.target);
    });

    var precisionInput = document.getElementById('precision');
    precisionInput.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    var format = createStringXY(event.target);
    mousePositionControl.setCoordinateFormat(format);
    });
}
```

Comment: _"which mean such attriburtes do not exist"_ - not exactly. It means VS Code's Linter couldn't find any reference to it. You could enable it by casting the object with it's right type.

Comment: Can't you just console.log(event) and have a look at your output in the browsers console? There you could see which variables you can access. This may not be browser-independent, but could give you a good starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem via type casting as follows:

```
mousePositionControl.setProjection((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
var format = createStringXY((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
```

Comment: Your first event target is not an `HTMLInputElement`, its an `HTMLSelectElement`.

Answer (score 1):

The `target` in `event.target` is of type `EventTarget` and every `HTMLElement` inherits from it. Therefore, any HTML element you receive with `document.getElementById()` method is an `EventTarget` and **the available properties will vary based on the specific element type**. The documentations -

- [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)
- [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

With the following code -

```js
var projectionSelect = document.getElementById('projection');
projectionSelect.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    mousePositionControl.setProjection(event.target.value);
});
```

even though at runtime you'll receive a specific type of `HTMLElement` through the `event.target`, at compile time it represents just an `EventTarget`, and as you can see from the documentation, `EventTarget` does not have a property named `value`.

If you put the above code in a JavaScript file and open it in VS Code, it will not complain about the `value`, because JavaScript is a dynamically typed language and VS Code is not trying to enforce type checking.

But if you put the same code in a TypeScript file, VS Code will try to apply type checking and find out that `EventTarget` does not have a `value` property.

To mitigate the error VS Code is showing you can cast `event.target` as `any`, and an `any` type can have any property -

```js
mousePositionControl.setProjection((event.target as any).value);
```

Or, since you know that the elements returned by your `document.getElementById()` methods represent a `select` element and an `input` element, you can cast them as `HTMLSelectElement` and `HTMLInputElement` -

```js
mousePositionControl.setProjection((event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value);

// and
var format = createStringXY((event.target as HTMLInputElement).valueAsNumber);
```